# Use openssl 1.0.0 with Qt 4.8.3 on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, openssl, qtwebkit

When I use openssl 0.9.8 with my qtwebkit-based application built with Qt 4.8.3, I got a lot of ssl errors. If I use openssl 1.0.0, there are no errors. However, Mac only comes with openssl 0.9.8 and 0.9.7 by default. No openssl 1.0.0 is included in the default installation. Therefore, I would like to deploy libssl.1.0.0.dylib within my application bundle. Qt loads the ssl library dynamically with mac API dlopen. Therefore, it only searches the path given in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I know I could create a shell script to launch the application with modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH (That's how people deploy apps on linux). But it doesn't seem to be the standard practice on mac. I don't want to install the openssl 1.0.0 into the system path either.

Please advise what is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You change the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on OSX.

Comment: Basically I don't want to change environment variables. Modifying environment variables will require us to launch the app with a shell script. I don't think that's a good practice on Mac.